# How to bypass main facebook url and get only pagename without slash in php?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, facebook

I am trying to make widget in wordpress site, in which i am going to use facebook iframe. For that i need to get only name of facebook page from full url that user inserted into widget.I am trying this but returns only facebook.com, i want to get only pagename, any help should be appreciated..

```
$input = trim($facebook_link, '/');

    // If scheme not included, prepend it
    if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
        $input = 'http://' . $input;
    }

    $urlParts = parse_url($input);

    // remove www
    $domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

    echo $domain;
```

Comment: What an Facebook URL looks like ? (Do not write an existing URL). Did you `var_dump($urlParts['host'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the Facebook URL would be something like this :

```
$myURL = "https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/";
```

So, to get only the `PAGE_NAME`, you can use [PHP Explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like this :

```
$myURL = "https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/";
$pageName = explode("/", $myURL)[3];
//explode() will return an array : 
//Array ( [0] => https: [1] => [2] => www.facebook.com [3] => PAGE_NAME [4] => )
```